# This code is to list all the running instances, its showing the error that "errorMessage": "'s3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'object'"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```
# This code was intended to list all the running instances that I have.
```

it is showing ""errorMessage": "'s3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'object'""
This code is intended to run on AWS Lambda. I am a beginner, and so if there are any other mistakes in this code, please do share your inputs.

```
import json
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource("ec2")
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Bucket("object")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    filters = [{"Name" : "instance-state-name",
    "Values" : ["running"]
    }
    ]

    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters = filters)

    RunningInstances = []

    for instance in instances:
        RunningInstances.append(instance.id)
        instanceList = json.dumps(RunningInstances)

    s3.object(
            'sameeeeeerjajs',
            'instanceList.txt'
    ).put(Body=instanceList)

    return("Status code:200")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From boto's docs for [S3.Object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object) it should be (`Object`, not `object`):

```
    s3.Object(
            'sameeeeeerjajs',
            'instanceList.txt'
    ).put(Body=instanceList)
```